# Error installing Angular using npm due to require-from-string

Tags: node.js, angular, installation, angular-cli

How to resolve this error as I am not able to install Angular.

Please see the below exception:

```
C:\Users\absin\node>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for require-from-string@^1.1.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'cosmiconfig'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\absin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-06T19_07_00_000Z-debug.log
```

even after temporal solution:

```
npm install https://github.com/floatdrop/require-from-string/tarball/v1.1.0 --save
npm install
```

still getting this [image: error]

Comment: node version v8.9.4 and npm 5.6.0

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9113

Comment: I just got the same error few minutes ago. It seems like a package deleted from npm.

Comment: i even dont have clue i have reinstall node js. i m using it on windows 10.  its showing me this error.

Comment: Have a look at the issue link I added. They give the impression this will clear up soon. Magic! :)

Comment: I am getting the same thing trying to create a brand new react app. It appears that the npm package is gone. Also, had a very similar thing happen with `read-all-stream-3.1.0`. It seems like something is up ...

Comment: I'm having the same issue when deploying an Angular app to Heroku

Comment: All of these missing packages are from `floatdrop`. Maybe he/she deleted the account? Yikes ...

Comment: someone on github claimed a deleted account wouldn't lead to deleted packages. no matter what, this is a pain....

Comment: https://twitter.com/npmstatus/status/949728719450460161

Comment: Im still getting the ERR 404 not found for `https://registry.npmjs.org/pinkie/-/pinkie-2.0.5.tgz` post npm issue resolution. They seem to be trying to fetch `v2.0.5` when it dosent exist, `v2.0.4` is the latest. It alos looks like `v2.0.4` was released 2 years ago? https://travis-ci.org/floatdrop/pinkie, or am I wrong here?

Comment: EDIT: Im still getting the ERR 404 not found for `https://registry.npmjs.org/pinkie/-/pinkie-2.0.5.tgz` post npm issue resolution. Problem seems to be that a dependency in my project, `pinkie-promise v2.0.1` is looking for `promise v2.0.5`, but after checking the `pinkie-promise v2.0.1` repo its looking for `^2.0.0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**some problem with NPM registry some of the packages got deleted.
They are restoring it... it will be available shortly**

Temp solution use the missing package from already running projects that or older projects.

Answer (score 8):

as stated in the issue link:

temporal solution:

`npm install https://github.com/floatdrop/require-from-string/tarball/v1.1.0 --save
npm install`

UPDATE:

It appears they are working on it. The require-from-string page used to return a 404, but at least now it loads the correct page on NPM's website: https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-from-string

Still doesn't appear to be working through `npm install` yet.

UPDATE 2:

An official response from NPM: https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/41zfb8qpvrdj

UPDATE 3: issue seems to be resolved.

Comment: temporary solution is working but again same issue while creating a new project using ng new command

Comment: temporal solution is not working when trying to install a fresh cli with -g (`npm install -g @angular/cli`) also I tried `npm install -g https://github.com/floatdrop/require-from-string/tarball/v1.1.0` seemed like a success. Any idea how to get that to work in the meantime?

Answer (score 3):

Even if https://status.npmjs.org/ says that it s all ok now,

the problem persist here

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. So when I used `yarn` it worked well and not having any problem to create new projects also.

```
yarn global add @angular/cli
```

again, when you create new app `ng new newapp` it will fail because at this moment npm is not able to find a package called `require-from-string`. But the you can run `yarn` to install all the packages. Yarn will ask which version of the `require-from-string` is needed. you can choose it.

Comment: wrong, you can only do so as you installed required packages on this machine before as "Yarn caches every package it downloads so it never needs to download it again". If you will try `yarn` on a fresh installation it will also fail. First with not having access to version 1.1.0 of `require-from-string` and eventually with `An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/pinkie-promise/-/pinkie-promise-2.0.1.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".`. It looks like `yarn` is just a (cheap) npm proxy as this reflects the current state there.

Comment: and you can `ng set --global packageManager=yarn` in order to always use yarn.

Answer (score 2):

npm is having issues.  This should just work.

Answer (score 1):

npm registry issue is now fixed according to https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/41zfb8qpvrdj

Solution

`rm ./package-lock.json`
`git commit -am "Removed broken package-lock.json file."`
`git push heroku master`