# Getting an error message creating a new app in Angular 5

Tags: angular, npm

Earlier today I created an Angular 5 app using the CLI. I do this all the time, and it worked fine.

Then I downloaded some code that was already in Angular 4. I deleted the /src folder from my newly created app, and replaced it with the /src folder of the code I downloaded. This didn't work too well. I tried running "npm install" to see if it would get past the error messages, but it didn't. So I just gave up at that point, deleted everything in the directory and tried to recreate it again from scratch using the CLI.

Since then, I can't create ANY new apps using the CLI, it keeps throwing a dependency error:

```
1569 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299 
1570 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Users\\toddh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli@latest" 
1571 verbose node v8.9.4 
1572 verbose npm  v5.6.0 
1573 error code ETARGET 
1574 error notarget No matching version found for require-from-string@^1.1.0 1575 error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting 1575 error notarget a package version that doesn't exist. 
1575 error notarget 
1575 error notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'cosmiconfig'
```

I tried uninstalling/reinstalling the Angular CLI as well as Node.js, but this same error is just stuck there.

Any thoughts on as how to fix this? I'm dead in the water at the moment.

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130877/error-installing-angular-using-npm-due-to-require-from-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error installing Angular using npm due to require-from-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130877/error-installing-angular-using-npm-due-to-require-from-string)