# create-react-app failing with error

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm trying to create a new react project with create-react-app but it's failing with the below error

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.3.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find any versions for "require-from-string" that matches "^1.1.0"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
Error: Received malformed response from registry for "timed-out". The registry may be down.
    at MessageError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:139:5)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:48907:15
    at next (native)
    at step (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:92:30)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:110:14
    at new Promise (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:93093:7)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:89:12
    at Function.findVersionInRegistryResponse (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:48946:7)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:48963:28
    at next (native)

Aborting installation.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodemon install error "No valid versions available for timed-out"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131550/nodemon-install-error-no-valid-versions-available-for-timed-out)

Comment: See also [Error installing Angular using npm due to require-from-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130877/error-installing-angular-using-npm-due-to-require-from-string)

Answer (score 3):

This is a temporary failure in npm registry ([source](https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/41zfb8qpvrdj))

Comment: any workaround or I should just wait for it to get fixed?

Comment: I'm afraid that if the package is not in your tree already there isn't much you can do. You can always try to use nwb instead of react-create-app as I don't think it requires that specific package