# get notarget No matching version found for require-from-string@^1.1.0 when run create-react-app

Tags: node.js

Here is my log:

```
stack require-from-string: No matching version found for require-from-string@^1.1.0
2331 verbose stack     at pickManifest (C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\index.js:65:11)
2331 verbose stack     at fetchPackument.then.packument (C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:52:18)
2331 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
2331 verbose stack
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error installing Angular using npm due to require-from-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130877/error-installing-angular-using-npm-due-to-require-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

npm is currently partially down, you'll need to wait a bit a retry later.

Get updates at https://status.npmjs.org