# require-from-string@^1.1.0 Error installing any package with NPM

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

Any package (even nodejs) results in this.
I have so far taken action :

1. Uninstalled all my dependencies
2. Cleared my cache
3. Reinstalled NPM / AngularCli

Running any NPM command will unfortunately result in this command, even the uninstall commands.

Sincethe debug file is too long, you can find a pastebin with the entire log [Here](http://here:https://pastebin.com/WzFR1uFG)

```
1567 verbose type range
1568 verbose stack require-from-string: No matching version found for require-from-string@^1.1.0
1568 verbose stack     at pickManifest (D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\index.js:65:11)
1568 verbose stack     at fetchPackument.then.packument (D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:52:18)
1568 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
1568 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
1568 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
1568 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
1568 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
1568 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
1568 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
1568 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
1568 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
1568 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
1568 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
1569 verbose cwd C:\Users\maart\Desktop\test
1570 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
1571 verbose argv "D:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@angular/cli"
1572 verbose node v8.9.4
1573 verbose npm  v5.6.0
1574 error code ETARGET
1575 error notarget No matching version found for require-from-string@^1.1.0
1576 error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
1576 error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
1576 error notarget
1576 error notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'cosmiconfig'
1577 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems npm servers are having problems.
Watch the following thread:

[get notarget No matching version found for require-from-string@^1.1.0 when run create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131398/get-notarget-no-matching-version-found-for-require-from-string1-1-0-when-run-c)